# Can't understand a short proof regrading analytic isomorphism in Serge Lang's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Its regarding the proof of Theorem 6.3 I can't seem to understand it. Could someone reelaborate it for me with a bit more detail?

[image: extract from the book]

Comment: Any part in particular, Mr. West?

Comment: @cmk the part where f(z)= a_0 + w^m . I can't seem to understand where it comes from.

Comment: Let $f$ be analytic at $z_0$ and $n\ge 1$ the least integer such that $f^{(n)}(z_0) \ne 0$, then $f(z)-f(z_0) = (z-z_0)^n g(z-z_0)$ with $g$ analytic at $0$ and $g(0) \ne 0$, $\varphi(t)=(f(t+z_0)-f(z_0))^{1/n} = t g(t)^{1/n}$ is analytic at $t=0$ and  $\varphi(0) = 0,\varphi'(0) \ne 0$, thus its inverse $\varphi^{-1}$ is analytic at $0$ and $f(z) = f(z_0) + \varphi(z-z_0)^n$

Comment: You notice that the original coefficients $a_n$ with $0<n<m$ are all zero?

Comment: @reuns thanks for the reply. It is very nice way of putting it and has helped me understand the topic even more. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can put the question as answered?

Comment: Your confusion might be that this part of the text *doesn't contain a proof* just an explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quoting @reuns's answer:

Let $f$ be analytic at $z_0$ and $n≥1$ the least integer such that $f(n)(z_0)≠0$, then
$$f(z)−f(z_0)=(z−z_0)^{n}g(z−z_0)$$
with $g$ analytic at $0$ and $g(0)≠0$. Then $$φ(t)=(f(t+z_0)−f(z_0))^{1/n}=tg(t)^{1/n}$$ is analytic at $t=0$ with $φ(0)=0$, $φ′(0)≠0$. Thus its inverse $φ^{−1}$ is analytic at $0$ and $$f(z)=f(z_0)+φ(z−z_0)^n$$